# Correct it so that it will compile and properly implement Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

Why won't the following program compile? Correct it so that it will compile and properly implement Comparable.

```
class Int implements Comparable
{
    private int x;
    public Int(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int compareTo(Int other)
    {
        return x - other.x;
    }
}
```

----//// im assuming that the compareTo method is wrong.. but i dont know why or  how to fix it.

Comment: @nickb That is not a reason to close. Bad questions are a reason to close. Homework is not. This question could fall under the latter, which would be a close reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The interface `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is defined with a type parameter of `<T>`.

If one does not provide a generic type parameter to a class or interface that requires it, then the default type parameter is assumed to be `Object`.

So, in effect, your class declaration reads like this:

```
public class Int implements Comparable<Object>
```

Now, this is where things get interesting.  `compareTo(T other)` takes the generic type parameter as its type argument.  If you don't explicitly declare the type to be something, then the method signature reads `compareTo(Object other)`.

Suffice to say, but `Object` and `Int` aren't the same object.  When you attempt to declare your method as `@Override`, the compiler will inform you that your method doesn't inherit or implement anything.

Ultimately, what this boils down to:  you have to fix your type parameter.  If you want to compare against `Int`, explicitly declare it so:

```
public class Int implements Comparable<Int>
```

Now, your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
class Int implements Comparable
```

With:

```
class Int implements Comparable<Int>
```

You need to specify what you're comparing to. If it's blank, then you need to compare Objects in `compareTo()`.

Comment: thank you for your response. i thought we couldnt have objects of an interface?

Comment: @user3424877 Elaborate what you mean by "couldn't have objects of an interface"; it'll help clear up whatever confusion you have there.

Comment: my apologies i mixed abstract class and interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class Int implements Comparable<Int> {
private int x;

public Int(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Int other) {
    return x-other.getX();
}

}
```